# Buttons and textfields randomly appear on applet - java

Tags: java, swing

I need to make a game as a assignment, but these textfields and buttons seem to randomly appear on top and bottom. This happends from start. I've checked already if all buttons and textfields are positioned right. Does anyone have a idea what could be causing this?

For any deeper look intro the code: [Github Repo](https://github.com/Watex/wakkenEnIjsberen)

[image: See above and bottom]

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: We won't look deeply in your Github repository to find the bug. Be more specific.

Comment: How could i be more specific? I have literally no idea where these fields and buttons are coming from. I've reviewed the code.

Comment: "*How could i be more specific?*" -> By providing something **smaller** than a ~800 code lines Github repository. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I looked at your code and it looks awful you're setting every position statically with `setBounds` instead of using layouts to position your elements. But putting that aside I would suggest calling `drawRect(0,0,width, height)` in the beginning of the `paint` method to clear the whole panel from anything that might have been drawn before. Don't forget to set the color you want.

Comment: @Masterzagh *"I would suggest calling `drawRect(0,0,width, height)` in the beginning of the `paint` method to clear the whole panel from anything that might have been drawn before."* Please stop giving advice until you can identify at least one problem with that comment.

Comment: You've override `paint` or `paintComponent` and failed to call `super.paintXxx`. Painting is much more complex than you seem to think it is, maybe have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understand

Comment: @AndrewThompson care to explain?

Comment: @Masterzagh Because "clearing the whole panel" doesn't even begin to describe the complex nature of the paint chain

Comment: I meant to say `fillRect` and `paintComponent`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer To me it looks like the fields got all cramped up and down when they were first added to the panel and when he started drawing the panel didn't update, leaving part of the old image with the fields still added in the old positions. Clearing the panel would solve this, as it would simply cover the old image with the background color.

Comment: @Masterzagh Your comments suggest that you don't understand how painting works and how custom paint should be done. If done correctly, there is no need to use `fillRect`, in fact, there should be no need to any custom painting at all, based on the OPs screen shoot

Comment: I also highly recommend that you take a look at [How to use borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

Comment: The assignment is by not using a layout manager and manually positioning each button, don't ask me why.

Comment: I seem to have overlooked and not used super.paintComponent(g). This solved all overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

This was not an issue. I simply have forgotten to use super on paintComponent ( i was thinking something was wrong with the actual buttons and textfields, or the order of them ).

`super.paintComponent(g)` solved the issue. How clumsy of me.

Thank you for all helpful responses! Especially @MadProgrammer :)